# ASP.NET MVC - NLog file target not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I have a problem with NLog.
I have configured the NLog in the file Nlog.config as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="d:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <target xsi:type="File" name="log" fileName="${basedir}\logs\${date:format=dd}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />


  <rules> 
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="log" />

  </rules>
</nlog>
```

And I get an error that **target log is not found**. I really don't know what I can do, maybe someone had similar problem.

I'm using .NET 4.5.

The Nlog.config is in the main directory of the project.
I set up the permissions to full access in the directories.

I tried to move the configuration into the web.config file, but the error still appear.

```
2016-07-26 09:17:25.6353 Warn Skipping unknown node: target
2016-07-26 09:17:25.6353 Trace ParseRulesElement
2016-07-26 09:17:25.6623 Error Error in Parsing Configuration File. Exception: NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Exception occurred when loading configuration from D:\Project\NLog.config ---> NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Target log not found.
   w NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseLoggerElement(NLogXmlElement loggerElement, IList`1 rulesCollection)
   w NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseRulesElement(NLogXmlElement rulesElement, IList`1 rulesCollection)
   w NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseNLogElement(NLogXmlElement nlogElement, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   w NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.ParseTopLevel(NLogXmlElement content, String filePath, Boolean autoReloadDefault)
   w NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.Initialize(XmlReader reader, String fileName, Boolean ignoreErrors)
```

Structure of the project:

[image: Structure]

**Update (after Michel A. answer):** I have also properties in NLog.config file

```
Build Action = Content
Copy to Output Directory = Copy always
```

**Update2:** I found the solution. The problem was that I have the backslashes instead of forward slashes

Wrong syntax:

```
fileName="${basedir}\logs\${date:format=dd}.log"
```

Correct syntax:

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/${date:format=dd}.log"
```

Comment: Check the /logs/ folder in your solution folder and check if the current user has read/write permissions on it (or if it exists). In your current picture it is not part of the solution, so this could be an issue.

Comment: I found solution. I made an update. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update2: I found the solution. The problem was that I have the backslashes instead of forward slashes

I'm pretty sure that wasn't the problem. The paths aren't evaluated on registering the target. Also on Windows the kind of slashes don't matter.

The problem is here that the XML is lacking the `<targets>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="d:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <target xsi:type="File" name="log" fileName="${basedir}\logs\${date:format=dd}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />


  <rules> 
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="log" />

  </rules>
</nlog>
```

It should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="d:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="log" fileName="${basedir}\logs\${date:format=dd}.log"
          layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="log" />

  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Hint: You get auto completion and error checking if you install the [NLog.Schema package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After checking my code, you're right also

Answer (score 0):

Is your NLog config file being copied into your bin folder ?

(check property file in Visual Studio)

Comment: My properties are: Build Action = content, Copy to Output Directory = Copy always

Comment: if you can see it in bin folder, it's not the problem, sorry I don't know what's happening to you

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using .Net Core 3.1 and had this exception: **"NLogConfigurationException: Target 'ownFile-web' not found for logging rule: *."** because my nlog.config file wasn't named right. It should be named as: **"Nlog.Config"**.